# is there any jquery plugin for support chat which also supports file sharing? or in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, jquery-plugins

I would like to know about any jquery plugin which supports live chat and also has file sharing feature in it. Is there any ? if not then what are the possible solutions to that?

Comment: One possible solution is to make your own jQuery plugin with file sharing and share that plugin with others

Comment: You are right, but at this time i dont want to dig into making my own plugin

Comment: asking for too much